# Exception interpretation of Bad version number in .class?

Tags: java, exception

Can anyone interpret this exception and give the solution?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
at de.az.j2eeoe.util.configtoolscanners.control.ftp.Ftp.uploadFileToServerViaJftp(Ftp.java:209)
at de.az.j2eeoe.util.configtoolscanners.control.UploadAction.actionPerformed(UploadAction.java:56)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1849)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2169)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:420)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:258)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:5517)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3129)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:1966)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:3984)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2024)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3819)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4212)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3892)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3822)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2010)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:1791)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3819)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:463)
at de.az.webutil.gui.WebEventQueue.dispatchEvent(WebEventQueue.java:34)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
    [21/03/2012 13:50:51:086] *** Before pollWebLogic Server, request #2
    [21/03/2012 13:50:51:090] *** After pollWebLogic Server, request #2 (duration: 4ms)
    [21/03/2012 14:00:51:127] *** Before pollWebLogic Server, request #3
    [21/03/2012 14:00:51:129] *** After pollWebLogic Server, request #3 (duration: 2ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

The class might have been compiled for a more recent Java version than what you are trying to run it with. I've had this problem myself a few times after having first installed JRE and then JDK, which caused the `PATH` environment variable to get a value that caused `java` to resolve to the executable in JRE's installation directory, while `javac` was resolved to the one in the JDK's installation directory.

Comment: When i run without Web-logic everything is OK but with Web-logic i get this exception.

Comment: @itro - well Web-logic must be configured to use an older JRE.

Comment: I did change it to 1.5 from file--> project structure but still the same. Did i change it from right place?

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown if the target JRE-version for which the class was compiled is higher than the running JRE-version. If you compile for JRE 1.6 but you run it on JRE 1.5, you get this error.

The solution is to update your JRE, or recompile the code with the proper target.

Comment: I use Intellij 10, is there a way to fix it within Intellij IDE?

Comment: Sorry but I have never used IntelliJ. But there must be something like that in IntelliJ. Maybe this can help: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/compiler.html#link3

Comment: After correcting as you suggested i get following error. seems to me much better. `cannot access net.sf.jftp.net.FtpClient
bad class file: C:\buildsystem\.m2\repository\org\objectweb\joram\jftp\1.52\jftp-1.52.jar(net/sf/jftp/net/FtpClient.class)
class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.` **How can i correct this one? this is 3th party library that i use.**

Comment: So I guess you force the compiler to target Java 1.5 but you used a library that has been compiled for target 1.6. So either you recompile yourself that lib (if it is compatible with Java 1.5), either you must use a JVM 1.6 You say that it does not work in your WebLogic server, maybe you could try to use an newer version of the JVM in WebLogic?